# Postgres not persisting granular units within time field

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres. I want to have default value for my date field to have granularity of minutes and seconds.

`ALTER TABLE engagements ALTER COLUMN event_date SET DEFAULT now();`

however, when I add a new row and query, all I see is `7-6-2020` which doesn't have the granularity I want. How can I fix this?

Comment: What data type is that column? If that is a `timestamp` and you only see `7-6-2020` then it's your SQL client that hides the time part

Answer (score 0):

I had to update column type from date to timestamp and then re-run an update to backfill the values:

```
UPDATE engagements
SET event_date = now()
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 999999;
```